# Find Frequent Word and its Value in Document Term Frequency

Tags: r, matrix, word-frequency

So I have to find the most frequent word and its value from a DTM.

```
library('tm') 
library("SnowballC")  
my.text.location "C:/Users/mrina/OneDrive/Documents/../"
apapers <- VCorpus(DirSource(my.text.location)) class(apapers)
apapers <- tm_map(apapers, removeNumbers) 
apapers <- tm_map(apapers, removePunctuation) 
apapers <- tm_map(apapers, stemDocument, language ="en")
```

This is for cleaning the Corpus and the below one creating the DTM and finding the frequency.

```
ptm.tf <- DocumentTermMatrix(apapers) 
dim(ptm.tf)
findFreqTerms(ptm.tf)
```

Is there a way to get the frequent word and the frequency value together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findFreqTerms` is nothing more than using rowsums on a sparse Matrix. The function uses slam's `row_sums`. To keep the counts with the words we can use the same functions. The slam package is installed when you installed tm, so the functions are available if you load slam or call them via `slam::`. Using the functions from slam is better as they work on sparse matrices. Base `rowsums` would transform the sparse matrix into a dense matrix which is slower and uses a lot more memory.

```
# your code.....
ptm.tf <- DocumentTermMatrix(apapers) 

# using col_sums since it is a document term matrix. If it is a term document matrix use row_sums
frequency <- slam::col_sums(ptm.tf)
# Filtering like findFreqTerms. Find words that occur 10 times or more. 
frequency <- frequency[frequency >= 10]

# turn into data.frame if needed:
frequency_df <- data.frame(words = names(frequency ), freq = frequency , row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: Just found out that `findFreqTerms` doesn't work with DTM, the way your mentioned gives the word with frequency and then I sort it to get the most frequent word `sort(frequency, decreasing = T)[1]`.

Comment: Is there a way it can show me the document name as well for the frequency term?

Comment: If you put the document name with the frequencies you just have a document term matrix. To put that into a data.frame use the following: `my_dtm_df <- data.frame(documents = ptm.tf$dimnames$Docs, as.matrix(ptm.tf))`

Comment: So since its DTM i used the `ptmDataFrame <- as.data.frame(inspect(ptm.tf))` function to get a more detailed info, but is there a way I can just get the most frequent term to show instead of all the other term?

Comment: Never use `as.data.frame(inspect(ptm.tf))` this only shows the first 10 rows and columns of a document term matrix. As I said earlier frequencies per document is just a document term matrix. You can't have a full row.sum of the terms and remap this to the documents. You would be double counting terms.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. So with this another method `n <- 1
top <- findMostFreqTerms(ptm.tf, n = n)
topp <- do.call(rbind, lapply(top, function(x){x <- names(x); length(x)<-n; x}))` I get the document names and the terms associated. But cant get the frequency alongside, anyway to fix it?

Comment: I think what we got right now should work. Thank You for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you you don't mind using another package, this should work (instead of creating DTM object):

```r
library('tm') 
library("SnowballC")  
my.text.location "C:/Users/mrina/OneDrive/Documents/../"
apapers <- VCorpus(DirSource(my.text.location)) 
class(apapers)
apapers <- tm_map(apapers, removeNumbers) 
apapers <- tm_map(apapers, removePunctuation) 
apapers <- tm_map(apapers, stemDocument, language ="en")

# new lines here
library(qdap)
freq_terms(apapers)                ^
```

Created on 2018-09-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: As much I wish i have to use the DTM, but this would definitely help someone else searching for something similar.